# Citing a funding application in a student thesis

Tags: citations, thesis

I gave an application for a funded project to a student as reference material for his Masters thesis. He wants to put a reference to this text into his bibliography. What is the necessary "bibliographic" information to include in this case, and what would be the recommended way to format such a reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule with citation of “unusual” references is always something like that:

1. Make sure you really want to cite it. *(In your case, it sounds okay, but most cases of students trying to cite “unusual” stuff end up with me telling them not to cite it)*
2. Include just enough information that the **cited item is uniquely identifiable**.
3. If the item is not publicly available, include additional information that hints at its content (such as the title).

For example:

> John Aristotle (341 BC). *Exploring the impact of introducing a fifth element in Empedocles’s classification of principles* [Grant X1FH25 proposal to the Macedonian Science Fundation, Agency for Philosophical Research].

Answer (score 0):

i know that we are not on the LaTeX / TeX  site, but when thinking about BibTeX your headache will gone away and it should be rather clear.

@format: That will be made when choosing a bibliograhystyle within your tex file.

@required information: Various bibliography items are demanding different fields.

[BibTeX overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX)

Comment: Which Bibtex entry type would you recommend for a funding application?

Comment: I disagree, afaict there is no specific bibtex item type for this so you would have to use something like @misc where virtually everything is optional and you have to work out how to map the information you want to include to the fields bibtex provides in a way that will provide satisfactory output.